# Splitting vectors into subvectors - Java

Tags: java

I have a function that processes vectors. Size of input vector can be anything up to few millions. Problem is that function can only process vectors that are no bigger than 100k elements without problems.

I would like to call function in smaller parts if vector has too many elements

```
Vector<Stuff> process(Vector<Stuff> input) {
    Vector<Stuff> output;
    while(1) {
        if(input.size() > 50000) {
            output.addAll(doStuff(input.pop_front_50k_first_ones_as_subvector());
        }
        else {
            output.addAll(doStuff(input));
            break;
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

How should I do this?

Comment: Is Vector still being used?

Comment: Vector was replaced by ArrayList in Java 1.2 (1998) An ArrayList can handle up to 2 billion elements, so if you are having problems it is not the Vector or ArrayList.  You will have to say what the problems are.

Comment: @anubhava I guess there are lots of old examples out there.

Comment: I would avoid trying to pop off 50K elements at a time as this could cause more problems than it solves and in the code above it is much more complicated.

Comment: @PeterLawrey `Vector` is the synchronized version of `ArrayList`, not a replacement. It still is legit for certain cases.

Comment: @Andy roseindia is a good archive for bad examples. ;)

Comment: @Andy Apart from APIs which mandate it, you can use ArrayList with Collections.synchronizedList if you need thread safety.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: A Vector should handle handle 2 billion elements just as well as ArrayList (which is too say, probably not too well, because you'll run out of heap memory in all likelihood).

Comment: Vector is converted into json string, sent to httpserver and then converted back into vector, which is why I need to send huge packets in smaller parts.

Comment: @KlausHelenius In that case I wouldn't use a Vector at all. I would process each piece of JSon using an event driven parser, this way you only need at least one entry in memory at any moment. i.e. make your code event driven and the problems are likely to go away (I am just guessing given you haven't said what they are)

Comment: @PeterLawrey: When sending the elements over HTTP it does make sense to batch a reasonable amount of them together to reduce the networking overhead.

Comment: @Thilo I am suggesting you stream all the data in one message in and one out. I agree making each event a HTTP request would be slow.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Currently the flow is:
Tuple -> POJO -> JSON -> Server -> JSON -> POJO -> Tuple

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem. I would do this is a stream fashion. i.e. using a single connection to the HTTP server to handle any number of tuples, one at a time.

Comment: Normally there would be only few hundred or thousand Tuples for single http request. But for some reason, for some uids there can be ridicculous amount of data, that needs to be split into smaller batches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to rewrite your doStuff method to take a List rather than a Vector argument,

```
public Collection<Output> doStuff(List<Stuff> v) { 
  // calculation
}
```

(and notice that Vector<T> is a List<T>)

and then change your process method to something like

```
Vector<Stuff> process(Vector<Stuff> input) {
  Vector<Stuff> output;
  int startIdx = 0;

  while(startIdx < input.size()) {
    int endIdx = Math.min(startIdx + 50000, input.size());
    output.addAll(doStuff(input.subList(startIdx, endIdx)));
    startIdx = endIdx;
  }
}
```

this should work as long as the "input" Vector isn't being concurrently updated during the running of the process method.

If you can't change the signature of doStuff, you're probably going to need to wrap a new Vector around the result of subList,

```
output.addAll(doStuff(new Vector<Stuff>(input.subList(startIdx, endIdx)))));
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if a Vector with millions of elements is a good idea, but Vector implements List, and thus there is [`subList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#subList%28int,%20int%29) which provides a lightweight (non-copy) view of a section of the Vector.

You may have to update your code to work with the interface List instead of only the specific implementation Vector, though (because the sublist returned is not a Vector, and it is just good practice in general).